# Can we have Settings.bundle settings showing for iPad and not for iPhone?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

Suppose I want to give permission to the user if he wants to rotate in iPad.
There is no rotation scheme for iPhone so I need not provide this option of iPhone settings.

Comment: You can check device, and `shouldAutoRotate` will return `true` iff the device is iPad. You can make a baseController to handle this scenario as well.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the device is iPad, you can do this:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //Setting for iPad
}
else {
    //Setting for iPhone
}
```

Similarly you can also do this:

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    //Setting for iPhone
}
else {
    //Setting for iPad
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BOOL isiPad;
//Declare global Bool value
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
// The device is an iPad 
// Enable rotation here
 isiPad=YES;
}
else {
// The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
// disable rotation here
}


//Set your rotation methods here 
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

        return isiPad;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your project

Target->Summery-> Supported Interface Orientations 
in that it gives settings for interface orientations for iPhone and i pad separately
Check it once

Like  below image
[image: See below image]

Answer (score 1):

Settings.bundle file is common in program. Its not like that if you an Universal application than you can have separate file for both iPhone & iPad. It will be 1 common file.

You should give validations by checking If iPad Device than you can open orientations or if iPhone Device & lock the Orientation.

Comment: @user3427687 disable means you can set only Specific Orientation mask for iPhone.